# Python Wordcloud in SVG Vector Format

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, word-cloud

I am generating some wordclouds using python wordcloud library, Wikipedia and Matplotlib. My intention is to save the wordcloud in SVG file in vector format. Currently the program is saving the file in SVG format but the contents are in raster format. Part of my codes are as follows:

```
# Import packages
import wikipedia
import re
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG') #set the backend to SVG
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Specify the title of the Wikipedia page
wiki = wikipedia.page('Puzzle')
# Extract the plain text content of the page
text = wiki.content
# Clean text
text = re.sub(r'==.*?==+', '', text)
text = text.replace('\n', '')


# Define a function to plot word cloud
def plot_cloud(wordcloud):
    fname = "cloud_test" 
    plt.axis("off")
    fig = plt.gcf() #get current figure
    fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
    plt.savefig(fname + ".svg", dpi=700, format="svg")
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
    
# Generate word cloud
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000, height = 2000, random_state=1, background_color='black', colormap='Pastel1', collocations=False, stopwords = STOPWORDS).generate(text)
# Plot
plot_cloud(wordcloud)
```

Here is the result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2ux72dtq62atkd/cloud_test.svg?dl=1

Comment: _contents are in raster format_ would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Content means when I opened the svg file with a browser and view source I saw "data:image/png;base64" meaning a png file actually embedded on svg file.

Comment: I added the result svg please take a look if you got some time

Comment: Please refrain from uploading the images to dropbox, post the images directly on the question instead

Comment: I tried but the image is in svg format. Uploading svg is not supported here

Comment: In that case you can upload a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237307/discussion-between-katherine-elizabeth-kath-and-luke).

Comment: ok. My intention is to show the svg code not the image itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save your figure you can use:

`plt.savefig(fname, dpi=700)` to `plt.savefig(fname + ".svg", dpi=700, format="svg")`

Remember to call this before `plt.show()`

Your function should look like

```
def plot_cloud(wordcloud):
    fname = "cloud_test" 
    plt.axis("off")
    fig = plt.gcf() #get current figure
    fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
    plt.savefig(fname + ".svg", dpi=700, format="svg")
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
```

Comment: I tried the change but got same output.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I used exact same function and got a blank svg file

Comment: Would you mind posting  a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ok. I am updating the code with my complete code.

Comment: I updated the code and here is the output svg https://www.dropbox.com/s/cthlw9lra9qqg2s/puzzle.svg?dl=1

Comment: @KatherineElizabethKath I have tried the code and it does save as a `.svg`

Comment: Yes it is saving svg but a blank one. There is nothing inside

Comment: @KatherineElizabethKath I'm getting a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`  are you sure the rest of your code is working fine?

Comment: I am not getting error. Everything working fine

Comment: My I see your code? I mean your version

Comment: Same as the one above, I've also tried with other matplotlib plots and it works

Comment: Any final solution or idea? I also tried with various changes nothing worked

Comment: Try running `plt.savefig("filename.svg", dpi=700, format="svg")` with any other plot like a bar chart and see if it works